# Why would you have a clustered composite index when none of the fields are used together?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2000, clustered-index, composite-index

In a legacy database (SQL Server 2000), we have a clustered index that looks like this:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_usr] ON [dbo].[usr] 
(
    [uid] ASC,
    [ssn] ASC,
    [lname] ASC
)
```

The thing is, as far as I know none of these fields are used together in a WHERE clause.  Nor is there really any reason to use any of them together.  Is there any reason to have a clustered index like this?

Comment: It could have been suggested by the SQL Server Profiler tool, although I'm not sure if that runs on Sql Server 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason I could think of is if you are using just those fields in many select statements (not necessarily in the where clause), it could serve as a covering index.

For example, if you have lots of queries like this:

```
SELECT uid, ssn, lname FROM usr WHER uid = x
```

The query would never actually have to hit the table as all required fields are in the index.

Comment: Now that you mention it, that does actually seem to be the case.